# How to speed up this Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I call this query 30,000 times - in total, it takes about 60 seconds - too slow. It's in-memory data (not called database in this query).

```
return Groups.Where(g => 
    g.Rules.Any(r =>
         r.PriceTypeId == priceType.Id && r.Filters.Any(f => 
             productC.AppliedFilters.Any(ap => ap.filterId == f.Id)))).ToList();
```

Any idea how to optimize this query?

Comment: Create a `ToLookup` of PriceTypeId and filterId. Don't do linear searches on values that should be in a dictionary.

Comment: If it is in-memory data, then it has nothing to do with EF/EF Core. Please remove these tags and EF Core from the title.

Comment: What takes 60s? The 30000 calls? And what kind of data amounts is this about?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your classes look like:

```
record Filter(int Id)
record Rule(int PriceTypeId, Filter[] Filters)
record Group(int Id, Rule[] rules)
```

If you make a lookup that maps a particular filterId/rulePriceTypeId tuple to a Group as a one time op:

```
var lu = Groups.SelectMany(g => 
  g.Rules.SelectMany(r =>
    r.Filters.Select(f => new { K = (FId: f.Id, RId: r.PriceTypeId), V = g })
  )
).ToLookup(at => at.K, at => at.V);
```

Then you can take a list of appliedfilterId integers and a rulePriceTypeId integer and look all of them up. Some duplicated Groups might return so we can clobber them out with a Distinct if it's important:

```
var gs = appliedFilterIds.SelectMany(af => lu[(FId: af, RId: rulePriceTypeId)]).Distinct();
```

We use SelectMany rather than select because the lookup potentially returns multiple groups for a given filter/rule id.. SelectMany expects to be fed a collection so it essentially unpacks the "list of Group lists" we could generate, to a single list of Group, that's distincted